# executing SQL breaks editor groups in vscode

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode with extension [Oracle.oracledevtools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Oracle.oracledevtools) to execute SQL. Executing command "Oracle: Execute SQL" breaks editor groups. Example:

Before executing SQL:

[image]

After executing SQL:

[image]

Executing SQL should not pull the results window from the other editor group to the one with sql file. It worked properly some time ago, but at some point this behaviour (bug?) was introduced.

Any ideas how to make executing SQL not break my existing editor groups? Thank you.

**What I tried already (with no success):**

- installing older version of oracle extension (v19.3.4)
- Pinnig the results editor window

**I use:**

- vscode: 1.63.2
- remote (through ssh) project in vscode
- extension Oracle Developer Tools: v21.3.0
- Linux Manjaro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was an issue with Visual Studio Code 1.63 that was fixed in 1.64 so it is likely fixed for you now.  Let me know if it is not. More info: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138914

Comment: It is fixed indeed in my vscode v1.66, thank you